# Use Arduino to store weather data in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I wrote one program that reads weather data from meteorological station through microphone input. I have now ordered an Arduino Mega, but before it arrives, I want to ask some questions.

If I use Arduino to read data from weather station and put it into some array (let's call it `A`), and then include a header file with that array, could I use that array in my `.cpp` file where the rest of my program is?

In short, I don't want to edit my program; I just want Arduino to read the data into an array.

Comment: You do know that header file inclusion is only done at time of compilation, not at run time? So doing it that way will only give you old sttic data, not live data from the station. Other than that then yes it's possible.

Comment: Could you help me how to do it at runtime?

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to accomplish. Forget about the array, the cpp and the header file: these are only details of a misguided implementation. Try to describe your problem at a higher level, and if it turns out not to be a programming problem (which is likely), post your question at http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use your program to send this array to `Arduino` via `Serial`.
Your `Arduino` must be connected to your computer and will recieve the weather data. Then you decide what to do with it.
If you put info in an array in a `.cpp`, you only could reload info via recompiling Arduino code with new `.cpp`.
Try to explain your answer in upper level.